# git ssh permission denied for the wrong user

Tags: git, ssh

Using a simple git command like this

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I am getting:

> ```
> ERROR: Permission to oresoftware/tsc-multi-watch.git denied to alex-teros.
> ```

I tried switching the user:

```
git config credential.username 'oresoftware'
```

but got the same error.  I have this in ~/.ssh/config

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
ControlPersist 2h

Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes

GSSAPIAuthentication no
ServerAliveInterval 240
ServerAliveCountMax 3


Host the1mills.github.com
     HostName github.com
     User the1mills
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/the1mills


Host oresoftware.github.com
     HostName github.com
     User oresoftware
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/oresoftware


Host bitbucket.org
     HostName bitbucket.org
     User oresoftware
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/oresoftware

Host alex-teros.github.com
     HostName github.com
     User alex-teros
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?
The obvious **problem** is that it's saying I am 'alex-teros' but I want to be 'oresoftware' for this command.

Comment: What is the url of `origin`? (Run `git remote get-url origin`)

Comment: origin is: `git@github.com:oresoftware/tsc-multi-watch.git`

Comment: I think the `Host` in your `~/.ssh/config` should not contain the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your ssh config to be used, your URL should use one of its entry (referening github.com)

For instance:

```
oresoftware.github.com:oresoftware/tsc-multi-watch.git
```

Then, and only then, the right private SSH key ( `~/.ssh/oresoftware`) would be used.

You only need to replace `User oresoftware` by `User git`: when pushing to GitHub n SSH, the user is *always* `git`.

Comment: the git remote url? right now it's `git@github.com:oresoftware/tsc-multi-watch.git`, what should I change that to?

Comment: even though I have `origin  git@the1mills.github.com:the1mills/siamese.git (fetch)`, it still says:  `ERROR: Permission to the1mills/siamese.git denied to alex-teros.` alex-teros is the wrong user, I want to be `the1mills` for this operation.

Comment: @MrCholo The git@github: part needs to be replaced by the config Host entry which would be using the right private key. `git remote set-url origin oresoftware.github.com:oresoftware/tsc-multi-watch.git`